# Weighting in synonyms with jaccard similarity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, similarity

I'm working on a dataframe where my data is as follows

```
0    cultureclash future spacewar action adventure ...
1    ocean drugabuse exoticisland adventure fantasy...
2    spy basedonnovel secretagent action adventure ...
3    dccomics crimefighter terrorist action crime d...
4    basedonnovel mars medallion action adventure s...
```

I would like to calculate jaccard similarity between each row, but taking into consideration synonyms for each word.
E.g. 'war' and 'warfare' would have been evaluated as similar.

Any idea on how to do that?
I have something in mind to get synonyms for each word, just not sure how to calculate jaccard similarity with them.

Comment: Do you want to use Jaccard similarity for a specific reason, or would more common string similarity measures also be ok?

Comment: @RobertHaas jaccard similarity for a specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could use e.g. `scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard`, which is a distance measure that operates on vectors. Thus, the sentences need to be converted to vectors first, i.e. one needs to create an embedding. Here, I am using a simple embedding method where each sentence gets mapped to a vector that is as long as the number of unique words in all sentences, and where the `i`-th entry of the vector is `1` if the `i`-th word in the vocabulary occurs in that sentence and `0` otherwise. Once each sentence is associated with a vector, the `jaccard` distance can be computed for each pair of sentences and stored in a matrix `distances`. To then convert the distances to `similarities`, simply invert the distances.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.spatial.distance import jaccard

df = pd.DataFrame([
    'cultureclash future spacewar action adventure',
    'ocean drugabuse exoticisland adventure fantasy',
    'spy basedonnovel secretagent action adventure',
    'dccomics crimefighter terrorist action crime',
    'basedonnovel mars medallion action adventure',
], columns=['sentence'])

vocabulary = set()
for sentence in df.sentence:
    vocabulary.update(set(sentence.split()))
vocabulary = sorted(vocabulary)

n = df.shape[0]
embeddings = np.zeros((n, len(vocabulary)))
for i, sentence in enumerate(df.sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    indices = [vocabulary.index(w) for w in words]
    embeddings[i, indices] = 1

distances = np.diag(np.zeros(n))
for (i, a), (j, b) in list(combinations(enumerate(embeddings), 2)):
    jaccard_distance = jaccard(a, b)
    distances[i, j] = jaccard_distance
    distances[j, i] = jaccard_distance
distances = pd.DataFrame(distances)
similarities = 1 - distances
print(similarities)
```

prints

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 0.111 | 0.25 | 0.111 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 0.111 | 1.0 | 0.111 | 0.0 | 0.111 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 0.111 | 1.0 | 0.111 | 0.429 |
| 3 | 0.111 | 0.0 | 0.111 | 1.0 | 0.111 |
| 4 | 0.25 | 0.111 | 0.429 | 0.111 | 1.0 |

where the entry at index `(i, j)` represents the similarity between sentence `i` and sentence `j`.

Note that (depending on the use case) this embedding technique may be too simplistic. A more sophisticated embedding technique may not only give better similarity scores (i.e. scores corresponding more closely to human-perceived similarity), but also account well for synonyms already. Alternatively, you could manually "unify" all synonyms (e.g. replacing all occurrences of words considered synonyms by a fixed word) before embedding.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I couldn't see how your example would account for synonyms, though. did I miss something?